# Agent Pool in Anylogic Software

Tags: anylogic, pool, agent

Where I can found the element "Agent Pool" in Anylogic?

I have already tried to research it in different parts of the software, but I can not understand if I have to set up the option that shows me it or it's already available but I didn't research in the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an agent population, you need to drag in an existing agent type from the projects view.

Or you drag on the "Agent" from the agent palette and select to create a population.

If you mean something else, please edit your question. There is no "agent pool"